# In HTML5, can I play the same sound more than once at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I'm making a game, in which sounds are often played. I noticed that a sound wont play again while it is being played. For example, the player collides with a wall, a "thump" sound is played. But, if the player collides with one wall, and then quickly collides with another wall, only one "thump" sound is played, and I believe that this happens because the first sound didn't finish. Is that true? How should I avoid this? I thought of preloading the sound three times, always playing a different copy of that sound, but this seems rather stupid...

**SOLVED:**

Turns out I was right... You need to preload multiple versions of the sound and then circularly play them.

**THE CODE:**

```
var ns = 3; //The number of sounds to preload. This depends on how often the sounds need to be played, but if too big it will probably cause lond loading times.
var sounds = []; //This will be a matrix of all the sounds

for (i = 0; i < ns; i ++) //We need to have ns different copies of each sound, hence:
    sounds.push([]);

for (i = 0; i < soundSources.length; i ++)
    for (j = 0; j < ns; j ++)
        sounds[j].push(new Audio(sources[i])); //Assuming that you hold your sound sauces in a "sources" array, for example ["bla.wav", "smile.dog" "scream.wav"] 

var playing = []; //This will be our play index, so we know which version has been played the last.

for (i = 0; i < soundSources.length; i ++)
    playing[i] = 0; 

playSound = function(id, vol) //id in the sounds[i] array., vol is a real number in the [0, 1] interval
{
    if (vol <= 1 && vol >= 0)
        sounds[playing[id]][id].volume = vol;
    else
        sounds[playing[id]][id].volume = 1;

    sounds[playing[id]][id].play();
    ++ playing[id]; //Each time a sound is played, increment this so the next time that sound needs to be played, we play a different version of it,

    if (playing[id] >= ns)
        playing[id] = 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you using to play the audio? I assume it is the `<audio>` tag.

Comment: `sound = new Audio("souce.wav"); sound.play();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the sound several times to simulate polyphony. Play them in round-robin fashion. Check out my demo at [matthewtoledo.com](http://matthewtoledo.com).  Specifically, the function _initSoundBank()

Comment: Yep.  That's the best way I found.  If anyone has a better solution, I would really like to know.

Comment: Late to the party, but you can also just "fake" your round robin by never playing the original: preload your clips, and then use `audio.cloneNode(true).play()` instead, so that you _always_ get a fresh copy playing.

Answer (score 7):

You can clone the audio element. I don't know if you can play them more than once simultaneously, but here is how you can play a sound more than once without downloading it more than once.

```
var sound = document.getElementById("incomingMessageSound")
var sound2 = sound.cloneNode()
sound.play()
sound2.play()
```

I know this works for chrome, which is the only place I needed it. 
Good luck!

Comment: Since i created an audio tag with a source tag as a child (`<audio><source src="sound.mp3"/></audio>`), I needed to set the optional `deep` param to `true` (`sound.cloneNode(true)`) in order for the play method to work on the cloned node.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a single `<audio>` object can only play one track at a time.  Consider that the `<audio>` object has a `currentTime` attribute that indicates the current position of the audio track: if an `<audio>` object could play multiple tracks are once, what value would `currentTime` reflect?

See my solution for a superset of this problem on [Is playing sound in Javascript performance heavy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078463/is-playing-sound-in-javascript-performance-heavy/10078734#10078734).  (Basically, add duplicate `<audio>` tags with the same sound.)

Comment: Aha! I knew someone planted that idea in my head before... Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Although it is only implemented in FireFox and Chrome right now, in the future you should use  the **WebAudio API**, which is specifically designed for games and audio applications in the browser.

There you can play back any sound multiple times and do several other fun stuff with it.

A good tutorial for that is here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/games/

Answer (score 0):

```
class SoundPool {
  pool : HTMLAudioElement[] = [];
  constructor(sound:HTMLAudioElement) {
    this.pool.push(sound);
  }

  play() {
    let found = false;
    for(var i=0; i<this.pool.length; i++) {
      if( this.pool[i].paused) {
        this.pool[i].play();
        found=true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!found) {
      let a = this.pool[0].cloneNode() as HTMLAudioElement;
      a.play();
      this.pool.push(a);
    }

  }
}
```